# How to scale WebView displaying SVG to fixed pixel height?

Tags: java, svg, javafx, webview

I would like to display a svg graphic called `logo` on my JavaFX application. 
I decided to use the WebView and display the graphic via the WebView.

**FXML WebView**

```
<WebView fx:id="logo" 
    disable="true" 
    maxHeight="100" 
    minHeight="100"
    minWidth="100" 
    AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" 
    AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
    AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
```

**Part of the main Controller class**

```
@FXML WebView logo = new WebView();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    String logoUrl = Main.class.getResource("FILENAME.svg").toExternalForm();
    logo.getEngine().load(logoUrl);
}
```

The graphic displays, but the size is off. I would like to make it a fixed pixel height scale the width automatically. 
My problem is that I can only scale it by a factor, `logo.setScaleX(0.8d);` and `logo.setScaleY(0.8d);`, 
which is not good, because I would fiddle forever to find the right factor, also when changing the svg it would need re-adjustment,
which is also unwanted.

So, my question is: How can I scale the WebView (content) to a fixed pixel height (e.g. `100px`) where it keeps the aspect-ratio for width?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using maxWidht maxHeight or prefWidth prefHeight properties work for you?

If non of this work and the only option is to do it with scaleX & scaleY.
You can just write some kind of routine, that will do it for you.

```
class WebViewUtil {

    public static void scaleTo(WebView view, Int size) {
        double currentHeight = view.getHeight();
        double currentWidth = view.getWidth();

        double scaleX = size / currentWidth;
        double scaleY = size / currentHeight;
        double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        view.scaleX(scale); view.scaleY(scale);
    }

}
```

Comment: `maxWidht`, `maxHeight` etc. only crop the view and it looks like only half of the logo is shown.

Comment: your `scaleTo(WebView, Int)` didn't seem to do the trick for me. I assume `Int size` is the height/width in pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Does the width/height properties for the SVG file have anything to say? If so, have you tried setting them both to 100%?

Comment: Yes, the properties are there and are displayed the way the file has them. So far, I manually edited the file and scaled it to my desired height. However, how would that be done in Java?

Comment: Wait, I meant the width and height attributes for the svg-tag inside the SVG file. Have you set those to 100%?